# Flutter video_player exoplayer version

Tags: flutter, exoplayer, flutter-video-player

Is it possible to change exoplayer version used by video_player in Flutter?

I tried to change it from build.gradle of video_player library but I got many errors in exoplayer's Java files.

Comment: Would you please clarify why you need to change the backing player-ExoPlayer- version? why do you have to do that?

Comment: Because I made one application with native Android. In this application I used exoplayer version 2.10.5 and HEVC channels playing smoothly. Flutter's video_player library uses exoplayer version 2.14.1. I want to change it to 2.10.5. @xSuperMu